# Onclick menu button, website scrolls to div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scrollto

I'm making a personal portfolio in an infinte scroll website. Right now I have 4 divs (home, bio, work and contact). I have an header with a menu with 4 names, same as divs. So what I want to do is to have a trigger when I'm at the div "Home" and click on the menu "Work" I want the browser to scroll down to the third div whick is "Work". Hope I make myself clear :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For something really basic use this:

```
<a href="#work">Work</a>
```

or you can try jQuery plugin [ScrollTo](http://flesler.blogspot.co.nz/2007/10/jqueryscrollto.html)

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/x4wDk/89/)

Comment: that code just opens a blank page. About the ScrollTo plugin, I have no clue how to use it.

Comment: it doesn't open a blank page. It scrolls down to that page.

Comment: For complete example You can hav a look at http://www.insitedesignlab.com/how-to-make-a-single-page-website/

Comment: It's working thank you, I'm new so, I messed up with the tags, now I just need an animation.

Comment: Glad that i could help you.

Comment: do you know how to make the animation that pna posted?

Comment: Are you talking about smooth scroll if yes then refer http://www.insitedesignlab.com/how-to-make-a-single-page-website/

Comment: Thats Nice...All Good Np :)

Answer (score 1):

If your Work section have a id, for instance `work` you can do it with:

```
$('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $("#work").offset().top}, 2000);
```

with some smooth animation

Comment: Where do I paste this?!

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `<a href="#work">Work</a>` method as @Jatin already pointed out.
However you should also modify your divs for it. For example the work div should look like this:

```
<div id="work">........</div>
```

For more information check [this page](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/links.html).